# How bad is running `crontab -l | sh` as root?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I meant to run `crontab -l | grep sh`, but accidently ran `crontab -l | sh`.  How likely is it that this actually ran any commands?  I saw a lot of shell errors about command not found (because lines began with numbers), but only saw the tail end of the output.  What did it likely do?  How likely was it to have run a command?

I think that any redirections in the crontab actually created or truncated files, but I'm wondering if any of the commands might have run.  The crontab contained comments (#), regular crontab formatted jobs, and blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what was in your crontab.

If you set any environment variables in it, you should probably check and fix them.

Apart from that, you should be okay. Your shell (should) have stopped attempting to execute each line at the first `*`, unless the expansion itself produced a valid command.

Comment: Thanks, no, there were no variables set in the crontab.

Comment: I'm curious, what does the asterisk have to do with it, or is it just that it's not a valid command?

Comment: If you happened to have an invalid command/entry in crontab - let us say `rm -rf /` then it could be pretty bad ;-)

Comment: @Andy, the asterisks would expand to a list of files in the current directory. How likely is it that those file lists would be commands that would actually do anything?

Comment: The asterisk is used by `sh` for wildcard expansion. By default, it represents all files in the current directory. Because the name of a file isn't (normally) a valid command, it should fail. However, if you had a file named like a command (for example, `cd`), `*` would expand to it and the command would be evaluated by the shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think likely. Even if there were they would not be dangerous  to run.

Comment: @MichaelPetch the cron tab is valid, and nothing like rm -rf

Comment: @Andy you should be fine, then.